# How to 'reach' Neo4j bolt within a Docker container containing Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, docker, neo4j

A bit of an esoteric question so not really expecting a solution, but here goes.

So I've began moving everything into Docker containers to get ready for production.

I understand how to connect my containers to the network I've set up so that they can talk to each other. ALL containers are able to talk to each other, all of them are connected to the network, etc., however, my Angular app can't connect to my Neo4j database driver and there are zero errors anywhere other than not being able to connect to the driver.

Now, instead of something like the following that works in all the other dockerized apps that would connect to a Docker network (where node_textract is the name of a container):

```
this.extractUrl = 'http://node_textract:3000/api/extract';
```

the line for connecting to the Neo4j driver is (where neo4j is the container):

```
const uri = 'bolt://neo4j:7687';
```

Note that I have a Node dockerized app that also uses this for Neo4j and it works fine, so it's not an issue with neo4j container not working.

Now if I just do a regular 'ng serve' and replace the above 'neo4j' with 'localhost' it will work fine... the only time it doesn't work is when inside the Docker container.

While I have no idea what is going on, I would suspect that is the culprit is 'bolt' in some way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your trying to get your client side AngularJS application to speak to a Neo4J database?

Your client-side JS won't be able to use the container name, instead you need to publish the port of the Neo4J container to the host.

If you're using `docker run` to run your containers, you can add `-p 7687:7687` and setup AngularJS to connect on `bolt://127.0.0.1:7687`

Comment: Yep, forgot fundamentals again ;)

Comment: As a sidenote, someone pointed out that it's completely unnecessary to dockerize an angular app since it gets pushed to the browser anyway. Oops, lol.